# Redirecting after click on button throws error ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I used regular button to throw span into button. I also made onServerClick function (to handle the event).

```
<button id="btnCancel" runat="server" class="btn btn-default pull-right" onserverclick="btnCancel_Click"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-magenta"></span>Cancel</button>
```

This should be simple cancel button that should exit the form and noting else. But for some reason C# function throws exception on redirect.

Here is the function:

```
            try
        {
            Response.Redirect("StartPage.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Warn("Error happened", ex);
            Response.Redirect("Error.aspx", false);
        }
```

Also if I just dont put try and catch block everything works fine.

Comment: have you inspected the error being thrown? if i remember correctly, some webform functions that deal with routing uses exception as a cheat to escape the entire pipeline. **edit**, [they did](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8), it said *"`Redirect` calls `End` which throws a `ThreadAbortException` exception upon completion."*

Answer (score 1):

[`Response.Redirect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8) throws a `ThreadAbortException` that is caught by your exception handler. Either

- remove the exception handler (if the real-life code is as simple as your sample, there should be no need for an exception handler) or
- move the `Response.Redirect` out of the exception handler or
- create a dedicated handler for the `ThreadAbortException` like this:

---

```
try
{
    Response.Redirect("StartPage.aspx");
}
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
  // Exception is expected, do nothing
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Warn("Error happened", ex);
    Response.Redirect("Error.aspx", false);
}
```